# Does only the space region movement due universe expansion affect the possibility of viewing a star?

Tags: speed-of-light, velocity, astronomy, space-expansion, observable-universe

My question is maybe simple and easy to answer because the intrinsic speed of the star affects only the final frequency of observed light but are there any tricks about the combination of object intrinsic velocity,space region velocity and maybe also the observer intrinsic velocity?

Comment: In cosmology there’s a distance called Luminosity distance which accounts for the space expansion and redshift effect. If you think about the Hubble measurement, we first measure the stars location via parallax and later on we use pulsars which has known brightness. These effects leads to a definition of luminosity distance which we can later on infer the Hubble constant or the rate of expansion of the universe. So simply, measuring the Hubble constant locally is exactly what you are describing.

Comment: But in general there’s no exact/certain way to distinguish cosmological redshift from redshift due to proper velocity.